# Reporting and filtering dates in access 2007?

Tags: date, ms-access, reporting

I'm having a customer look up a report between FROM and TO dates. Basically for any month a client can request a report, what I need to do is show the QTY of units in the inventory as of the last day of previous month. So if client is looking to make a report for 12/23/2015 - 12/28/2016 then I need to show the QTY of units in inventory (beginning inventory) on 11/30/2015. I had someone recommend I use DateSerial, but it doesn't seem to do what I want it to do. Basically the FROM AND TO dates are values that I pass on from a Visual Basic application into an empty form and they get used in the report.

I'm not sure if I need to make changes to my queries. Here's what the report does..

With the report, I need to be able to show the client the following...
ItemID

```
Beginning Inventory (as of last day of previous month)
Unit Price
Bought Units (for report date)
Sold Units (for report date)
Returned Units (for report date)
Subtotal (of bought +sold+returned)
Inventory on hand (beg + subtotal)
```

So what I do is in my first query I get the Unit Price, and Beginning Inventory (currently not filtering by last day of previous month).

Then I have 3 more queries, one for Bought, Sold and Returned where I link the ItemID's and I filter the TransactionDate (between dates form!formdates!txtFrom and form!formdates!txtTo).

Then I have the last query where I combine the first one with the other 3. Now I'm pretty sure I should include the DATESERIAL() function in the first query? And filter the TransactionDate (this is the column i need to look through to count beginning inv, as well as look for Bought, Sold, Returned Items).

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

The DateSerial() function should return the last day of the previous month. Here is an example query for your problem:

SELECT ID, myDate
FROM Table1
WHERE (((myDate)=DateSerial(Year([enter start date:]),Month([enter start date:]),0))) OR (((myDate) Between [enter start date:] And [enter end date:]));

Documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx05d0c(v=vs.90).aspx